# Connecting with an external Camera using an Android device

Tags: java, android, camera

Im working on an app and I was wondering if it's possible to connect to a Digital Camera through the Android App I'm working on.

I'm doing this as a research for a backup plan, because I'm currently working on an Android app and the idea was to run it on an Android Camera that can connect throught 3G/4G, but it seems that those Camera's are pretty hard to find. So my supervisor asked of me to do some research regarding this matter, but all I've found at the moment is the Canon Camera-connect app, the problem with this is that I'd like to have this functionality inside my own application and not having to use an outside app. Also I've heard something about connecting to the device by making a hotspot from the device, but I'm not sure how that would work and I'm afraid that the user would have to do some stuff outside that app (like turning on the hotspot and connecting) which I would like to do automaticly from the app.

To be clear about what kind of functionalities I need for the app to do:

I would like that app to have a button to take a picture that, if pressed, would use the digital camera to take a picture and then send the picture to the device, so I could use it furhter on in the app.

Excuse me for my english, It's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a that'll probably work for me and that is using the [Camera Remote API](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) from Sony. I think this API in combination with a Sony Camera could work pretty well.